# Is there an M2Crypto installer for Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: python, windows-7, m2crypto

Is there an M2Crypto Windows installer for Python 2.7 64-bit?  If not is there a reason why one cannot be built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M2Crypto-0.21.1.win-amd64-py2.7 is available as part of the [ActivePython Business Edition](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/m2crypto/). M2Crypto is easy to build from the source distribution using Visual Studio 2008 but there are [legal reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_of_cryptography_in_the_United_States) why the binaries cannot be freely distributed.

Comment: There are legal reasons that the x86 version for Python 2.7 can be freely distributed (http://chandlerproject.org/bin/view/Projects/MeTooCrypto) but that the x64 version cannot be? Really?

Comment: Sure, but the restrictions apply equally to x86 and x64. The reason there's no binaries available for x64 isn't because of the legal restrictions: it's just because they've not built them. With their approval they could -- if they wished -- distribute x64 binaries as well as the x86 binaries they already have.

Answer (score 1):

You can try my Windows 64 build for Python 2.7:

http://brabenec.net/misc/packages/M2Crypto-0.21.1.win-amd64-py2.7.exe
http://brabenec.net/misc/packages/M2Crypto-0.21.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg

Comment: I installed the .exe file you provided. I tried to run it but it I got error saying: `python version 2.7 required which is not found in the registery`. I installed python 27 normally and placed it in the c: drive. Can you tell me how to add python in the registery.

Answer (score 1):

Install via pip: `pip install M2CryptoWin64` (for 64-bit Win) or `pip install M2CryptoWin32` (for 32-bit). See this [blog](http://the.randomengineer.com/2014/07/29/ssl-for-python-m2crypto-on-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

It needs to install openssl-1.0.1b to get rid of issue

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```